# Integrate by change of order

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{x}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}  \,dydx $$
tried by splitting the region in 2 where the line $$y = x $$cuts the curve $$y = \sqrt{2-x^2}$$
unable to find the limits

Comment: Try the substitution $y=xu$, then integrate wrt $u$

Comment: I think it should be $dydx$, not $dxdy$. Otherwise the innner limits make no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

Try [polar coordinates](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/integrating-multivariable-functions/double-integrals-a/a/double-integrals-in-polar-coordinates). The region

$$
D=\{(r,\theta): 0\le r\le \sqrt{2}, \pi/4\le \theta\le \pi/2\}
$$

So the integral is
$$
\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2}}(\cos\theta)\cdot r\ drd\theta
$$

[image]

---

If you only want to change the order of the integrals, your integral is

$$
\int_0^1\int_0^yf(x,y)dxdy+\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}\int_0^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}f(x,y)dxdy
$$

Basically, you split the domain into two pieces. The lower piece gives you the first integral and the upper piece gives you the second one.

[image]

Comment: this process is not in the syllabus

Comment: @hop: then please show me your syllabus.

Comment: how did you calculate the limits

Comment: can you explain the limits?

Comment: @hop I added a picture. Can you go on? You find the limits by looking at the picture.

Comment: @hop: to see how to set limits for double integrals on a general domain, check this tutorial https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/DIGeneralRegion.aspx

Comment: thanks you!! I did the same process I was facing problems with limits

Comment: @hop you are welcome. Can you please edit your question? In the integral, you should have $dydx$ not $dxdy$.